# How to assign HREF attribute from nodelist into a regular array?

Tags: javascript

So as you can see in the code below, the `downloadLinks` variable is a NodeList of `<a>` elements and I need to grab the **href** attribute and assign them into the **linkContainer** array. The for loop doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
( () => {

    "use strict";

    // Variables holding content to show & hide

    const tab1 = $("#default"),
          tab2 = $("#dim"),
   featureList = $("#default-wac-feature-list"),
 downloadLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#dropdown-download-links > li > a"),
 linkContainer = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < downloadLinks.length - 1; i++) {
      linkContainer[] = downloadLinks[i].href;
  }

  console.log(linkContainer);


}) ();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `i < downloadLinks.length` instead of `i < downloadLinks.length - 1`, and assign the link to an index - `linkContainer[i]` (or use `Array.push`).

```js
const downloadLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#dropdown-download-links > li > a"),
      linkContainer = [];

for (let i = 0; i < downloadLinks.length; i++) {
  linkContainer[i] = downloadLinks[i].href;
}

console.log(linkContainer);
```

```html
<ul id="dropdown-download-links">
  <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

An easier option would be to use `Array.from()` to convert the the NodeList to an array of hrefs directly:

```js
const downloadLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#dropdown-download-links > li > a");

const linkContainer = Array.from(downloadLinks, el => el.href);

console.log(linkContainer);
```

```html
<ul id="dropdown-download-links">
  <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake. Second one is what I'm going with, very clean! Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Node list can be a problem is you don’t know that they are not true arrays. I use a method detailed by [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array). It’s simple and straightforward.

```
var domElems = [].slice.call( downloadLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#dropdown-download-links > li > a") );
```

I run into this so often that I create a utility function for it.

```
function nodeToArray(domElems ){
    return [].slice.call(domElems);
}

// and then I use it like this.

var getDomArr = nodeToArray(document.querySelectorAll("#dropdown-download-links > li > a") );
```